# Query date in Access

Tags: datetime, criteria, ms-access-2010

I have a database that stores date and time in a single column for each entry as -
`8/29/2012 6:09:45 AM` - as an example. I am looking for a way to query just today's date all regardless of the time.

Currently I use criteria in a query `Like "*9/29/2012*"`. The issue is that each day that the report is needed the date in the criteria needs to be updated, eliminating the possibility to automate the report.

Is there a way to just to query current date with out have to overhaul the target tables, or having to update the query criteria daily?

Answer (score 0):

Dates are stored as numbers and the integer portion is the date, so you can say:

```
  CInt(MyDate)=Cint(Date)
```

You can also say:

```
 CDate(Format(MyDate, "yyyy/mm/dd")) = Date()
```

Or

```
 DateSerial(Year(Mydate),Month(MyDate),Day(Mydate))=Date()
```

Or

```
MyDate>=Date And MyDate<Date+1
```

This final example will take advantage of indexes.

```
29/09/2012 00:00:00 is equal to Date() 
29/09/2012 23:50:00 is greater than Date() but less than Date+1
```